# Make my module a command

Tags: linux, python-3.x, python-module

I'm pretty sure I read it somewhere but I can't find any doc about it anymore.

I did a python (3) module, let say I called it `addition`. I have my sources, my tests, my `setup.py` is OK. I can import & use it from anywhere in my system. It's OK.

What I would like now, is to define some commands to use it directly from the command line i.e.:

`add 1 2 # call addition.add(1, 2)`

It must be super simple but can't find anything like this (all my Google results are about how to create a shell, i.e. embed a CLI into Python. I want quite the opposite)

Thanks!

Comment: A really simple way to do is to add scripts (python, bash, perl..) into a `~/bin` folder in your home directory, and to add this folder into your $PATH variable.

Comment: Sure, but I wanted:
i) this to be done by `setup.py` for the final user
ii) to be able to define the command name & argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, autoanswering as I finally found it ([doc](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation)):

One must add to `setup.py`:

`setup(
    # other arguments here...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo = my_package.some_module:main_func',
            'bar = other_module:some_func',
        ],
        'gui_scripts': [
            'baz = my_package_gui:start_func',
        ]
    }
)`